# Easiest way to paginate data in divs

Tags: jquery, pagination

What is the easiest way of paginating data that is in divs? Some jquery library for it? Basically I would only need 1/x pages shoqing and arrow buttons to go throught all the data.

Answer (score 1):

See:

**[jQuery Pagination Plugin.](http://www.myjquery.co.uk/docs/x/plugins/pagination/jquery_pagination.php)**